# script to fetch oracle database table in csv format

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, spool

I am using this script as below

```
set colsep ','
set heading on
set headsep on
set pagesize 0
set trimspool off
spool C:\DXC\books11.csv
Select * from test_extract;
spool off
exit
```

but the problem with this is

```
ARKO                ,1A                  ,        20
ARKO1               ,1B                  ,        20
```

space is comming after the values of each attribute as per the lenght of the attribute.

required output :

```
ARKO,1A,20
ARKO1,1B,20
```

Comment: If you have access to sql developer, then it is as simple as `select /*csv*/ * from t;`  `https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/`

Comment: Are those CHAR or VARCHAR2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no `SET` command will help.

One option - that helps - is to name all columns you're spooling and concatenate them using desired column separator.

For example, this is what you currently have:

```
SQL> set colsep ','
SQL> set heading on
SQL> set headsep on
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> set trimspool off
SQL> select * From dept;
        10,ACCOUNTING    ,Zagreb
        20,RESEARCH      ,DALLAS
        30,SALES         ,CHICAGO
        40,OPERATIONS    ,BOSTON
```

But, if you do it as follows:

```
SQL> select deptno ||','|| dname ||','|| loc from dept;
10,ACCOUNTING,Zagreb
20,RESEARCH,DALLAS
30,SALES,CHICAGO
40,OPERATIONS,BOSTON
```

it looks as you wanted. Drawback? You'll have to type all those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLcl, it's in your SQL Developer bin directory, works like SQLPlus, only better.

It's SQL.exe on Windows for example, but also available as it's own 25mb download on [Oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html).

```
set sqlformat csv
spool file.csv
select * from table;
```

It'll give you exactly what you're asking for.